# Drupal MENU_LOCAL_TASK for views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Want to group two and more different views ("page" style) under tabs. Can't get it working, tabs didn't show. I guess the problem is that I didn't define page callback properly.

This is what I tried:

```
function general_menu() {

   $items = array();

   $items['people'] = array( // First view has path named "people"
    'title' => 'People',     
    'access arguments' => TRUE,
    );

    $items['people/list'] = array(
      'title' => 'People',
      'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    );

    $items['people/og'] = array( // Second view has path named "people/og"
      'title' => 'Groups',
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
      'access arguments' => TRUE,
          'page callback' => 'mymodule_link_to_group_create', // <- maybe wrong
    );

return $items;

}

// Not sure I need it
function mymodule_link_to_group_create() {
   drupal_goto('people/og');
}
```

How to properly define "page callback" for views?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
    $items['people/og'] = array( // Second view has path named "people/og"
      'title' => 'Groups',
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
      'access arguments' => TRUE,
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_link_to_group_create', // <- maybe wrong
    );

...

function mymodule_link_to_group_create() {
  return views_embed_view('YOURVIEWSNAME', 'DISPLAYID'); // displayid usually default
}
```

Comment: You can also set `views_embed_view` as page callback, and send arguments via `'page arguments' => array('YOUR_VIEW_NAME', 'DISPLAY_ID')`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just define the menu's in the view under Page Settings?

Comment: Yes, this was the first thing I thought of, but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to use the [Quicktabs module](https://drupal.org/project/quicktabs).